# Несколько моделей в одной форме

Tags: yii

Приветствую.

Есть модель (AR) - Photo. Поля `id, user_id, imagem, description`.

Необходимо в форме вывести несколько моделей (все фотографии, которые принадлежат пользователю) и проследить, чтобы пользователь у всех фотографий заполнил `description`.
В идеале, сохранить `description` фото, которые пользователь заполнил, по остальным показать ошибку.

Подскажите, если есть мысли, как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/) реализации с офф-сайта формы с двумя моделями.

Но, в этом случае, похоже, нужно смотреть в сторону [табличного ввода](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.table).

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже, что это как раз то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как оно делается при помощи генератора когда yii-шного уже не помню, но в HTML параметр name у полей должен името форму Model[][property], а не Model[property]. Тогда в контроллере $_POST['Model'] у тебя будет массивом, содержащим все модели. Останется обойти массив моделей и проверить/сохранить их.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Подумаю над этим.